# Saving image of specific area of GUI in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have devloped a GUI which browses mat files and draw plots in matlab now I want to save these plots as images using a save button in my GUI

I did the coding of save callback function as

```
[file,path]=uiputfile({'*.bmp','BMP'},'Save Image As');
f=getframe(handles.axes);
[x,map]=frame2im(f); 
imwrite(x,fullfile(path, file),'bmp');
```

But this code gives me just the graph without its axis labelled.

Someone suggested me to use `explore_fig` but i am unable to use it for my purpose

If I want to save specific area of my GUI as an image what code should I use

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, using [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) it grabs solely the contents of the axes and no more. In order to get the axes labeled, you can take advantage of the [`TightInset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#TightInset) property of the axes to find the bounding rectangle of the axes. The `TightInset` is the margin that is added to the axes `Position` to make room for labels.

Also, you can take advantage of the second input to `getframe` which specifies the rect (in pixels) to grab. You can compute this using `hgconvertunits` (undocumented).

```
% Position INCLUDING labels/ticks
position = get(hax, 'Position');
inset = get(hax, 'TightInset');
outerpos = [position(1:2) - inset(1:2), position(3:4) + inset(3:4)];

% Ensure that the units are PIXELS
rect = hgconvertunits(hfig, outerpos, get(hax1, 'Units'), 'pixels', hfig);

% Grab only the specified rectangle from the figure
im = getframe(hfig, rect);
```

If we do this on some sample data

```
% Load Sample Data
load mri
img = squeeze(D(:,:,12));

% Display axes in middle of figure
hfig = figure();
hax = axes('Position', [0.2 0.2 0.5 0.5]);
imagesc(img);
xlabel('columns');
ylabel('rows');
axis image;
```

The original looks like this

[image]

And the result of `getframe` with a rect is

[image]